# CDC vs Message Broker Key differences and which to use when

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, microservices, message-queue

I have been struggling to find any key pros and cons on using one over the other. When it comes to sharing data between two microservices. Especially when it comes to scale.

What my assumption and question is - if we use a CDC to queue & CDC (Queue) subscriber combination, we can more or less can get rid of the need to publish to the message queue from our application layer (which might be prone to more human errors).

I went into this thought process when evaluating Mongodb "changestreams" and have been curious ever since.

Answer (score 0):

When using CDC in this way, you're basically turning your microservice's database into a message broker.  That has the advantage of not requiring a separate message broker.  It has the disadvantages of deeply coupling the consuming microservices to the producing microservice, especially since every new consuming microservice will effectively impose some extra load on the source microservice's database.

CDC can be a reliable way to feed a pubsub topic on a message broker, however, though it's probably best to recognize that the CDC still means a coupling between the source microservice's internal data model and the data model for interservice communication, which tends to mean changes to one require changes to all.  Since one of the primary (and arguably the only always-valid-in-general) reasons to adopt microservices is to allow changes with minimal coordination, it might be advised to have the CDC feed a single service which is responsible for translating the CDC records into the wire model (e.g. domain events with an agreed upon schema).